# How to get today -"1 day" date in sparksql?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to get `current_date - 1` day in sparksql, same as `cur_date()-1` in mysql.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The arithmetic functions allow you to perform arithmetic operation on columns containing dates.

For example, you can calculate the difference between two dates, add days to a date, or subtract days from a date. The built-in date arithmetic functions include `datediff`, `date_add`, **[`date_sub`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_sub(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int))**, `add_months`, `last_day`,
`next_day`, and `months_between`.

Out of above what we need is

> date_sub(timestamp startdate, int days),  Purpose: Subtracts a specified number of days
>   from a TIMESTAMP value. The first argument can be a string, which is
>   automatically cast to TIMESTAMP if it uses the recognized format, as
>   described in TIMESTAMP Data Type. Return type: Returns the date that is > days days before start

and we have

> current_timestamp() Purpose: Alias for the now() function. Return
>   type: timestamp

you can do select

```
date_sub(CAST(current_timestamp() as DATE), 1)
```

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

Comment: Fair warning, the functions will return a DATE ONLY. All time components will be lost.

Comment: current_timestamp() as timestamp, if you want to keep time

Answer (score 18):

You can try

```
date_add(current_date(), -1)
```

I don't know spark either but I found it on google. 
You can also use this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) for reference

Answer (score 8):

You can easily perform this task , there are many methods related to the date and what you can use here is `date_sub`

**Example on Spark-REPL:**

```
 scala> spark.sql("select date_sub(current_timestamp(), 1)").show
+----------------------------------------------+
|date_sub(CAST(current_timestamp() AS DATE), 1)|
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                    2016-12-12|
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 7):

Spark SQL supports also the `INTERVAL` keyword. You can get the *yesterday's date* with this query:

```
SELECT current_date - INTERVAL 1 day;
```

For more details have a look at [interval literals documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-ref-literals.html#interval-literal).
I tested the above with spark 3.x, but I am not sure since which release this syntax is supported.

Comment: It worked great for me, because keeps the full timestamp as output.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -1), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `date_sub()` function is the right for the question, anyway, there's an error in the selected answer:

> Return type: timestamp

The return type should be `date` instead, date_sub() function will trim any `hh:mm:ss` part of the timestamp, and returns only a `date`.

Answer (score 0):

date_add and date_sub work best in databricks + python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).