# How to add day(+1) to date which is in (mm/dd/yyyy) using sparkSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with a column which has data in the form dd/mm/yyyy Now using the sparkSQL i want to add 1 day to the current date. I have tried with Date_add function but got an exception that the function doesnt exist

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this:

[Check the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

There is also a possible duplicate :
[How to get today -"1 day" date in sparksql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114875/how-to-get-today-1-day-date-in-sparksql)

If this does not get you anywhere please post the exact exception